# DragDropMode, взаимодействие между двумя QListWiget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, drag-n-drop, qlistwidget

Мне нужно запретить перетаскивание из одного `QListWidget` в другой, то есть оставить перетаскивание только в своем виджете.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QMainWindow, QApplication


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(539, 227)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 201))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.list_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.list_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 256, 201))
        self.list_2.setObjectName("list_2")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        __sortingEnabled = self.list_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.list_2.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий2"))
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.list_2.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.list_2.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook

    app.exec()
    sys.exit()
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> enum QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode
>
> Описывает различные события перетаскивания, на которые может воздействовать представление.
> По умолчанию представление не поддерживает перетаскивание (NoDragDrop).
>
> QAbstractItemView::**InternalMove** Представление принимает операции перемещения (не копирования) только от самого себя.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(539, 227)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 201))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.list_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.list_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 256, 201))
        self.list_2.setObjectName("list_2")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        __sortingEnabled = self.list_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.list_2.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий2"))
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.list_2.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)     # - DragDrop, + InternalMove
        self.list_2.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        
        self.listWidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove) # - DragDrop, + InternalMove
        self.listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]